# How to use .replace() on a string

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to clean a column of numbers (in string format), which contains B for billions rather than numerical values.

So I need to replace the decimal point and then also the B with '000' to convert to numerical form which I can then change to a float.

Here is my code

```
data['notional'] = data['Outst'].replace(' . ','')
print(data.head(10))
```

Can see from the output below that it doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

Output:

```
    Date            Issuer  Maturity Outst notional
0  06/08      GRIFFON CORP  03/01/28   150      150
1  06/08  BANK NOVA SCOTIA  06/15/23   300      300
2  06/08        FANNIE MAE  06/17/25    30       30
3  06/08       EQUINIX INC  07/15/27   500      500
4  06/08       EQUINIX INC  07/15/25   500      500
5  06/08       EQUINIX INC  07/15/50   500      500
6  06/08       EQUINIX INC  07/15/30  1.1B     1.1B
7  06/08       PHILLIPS 66  12/15/30   850      850
8  06/08       PHILLIPS 66  04/09/25   650      650
9  06/08   SIRIUS XM RADIO  07/01/30  1.5B     1.5B
```

If I use below code and change the entire string, it works. But this is not scalable for the entire dataset.

```
data['notional'] = data['Outst'].replace('1.1B','1100')
print(data.head(10))
```

output:

```
    Date            Issuer  Maturity Outst notional
0  06/08      GRIFFON CORP  03/01/28   150      150
1  06/08  BANK NOVA SCOTIA  06/15/23   300      300
2  06/08        FANNIE MAE  06/17/25    30       30
3  06/08       EQUINIX INC  07/15/27   500      500
4  06/08       EQUINIX INC  07/15/25   500      500
5  06/08       EQUINIX INC  07/15/50   500      500
6  06/08       EQUINIX INC  07/15/30  1.1B     1100
7  06/08       PHILLIPS 66  12/15/30   850      850
8  06/08       PHILLIPS 66  04/09/25   650      650
9  06/08   SIRIUS XM RADIO  07/01/30  1.5B     1.5B
```

Comment: There is no `' . '` spacedotspace so that seems normal no one is changed

Comment: Why not strip out the B and multiply it by a billion?

Comment: Was playing around with the code but using '.' gives same result. That's what I tried originally.

Comment: I added the Pandas tag since it seems like that's what you're using. LMK if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.replace()` only makes replacements when it finds a match to the **entire value**. Unless you have a value which is just ".", `.replace(".", "")` won't do anything.

To replace a character/sequence *inside* a string, you should use `.str.replace(".", "")`. That will replace every "." character in each string with nothing.

---

To actually replace your billions, I think you want

`.str.replace("(\d+)\.(\d+)B", r"\1\g<2>000", regex=True)`, which is extremely fiddly, but should replace everything you want.

Comment: Huh, that's confusing, but it makes sense when you think about it. This is `pandas.Series.replace()`, right? (I'm not too familiar with Pandas myself.)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. Easy solution.

Comment: @wjandrea Yes - `.str` lets you treat the columns as strings inside a container, rather than a column which happens to contain strings. As you say, it makes sense when it clicks, but it is a little counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

You may apply a method on each cell, using `Series.map()` and pass a function that will handle the different values

```
def parser(value):
    if 'B' in value:
        return float(value[:-1]) * 10 ** 9
    # add other cases if other letter,for million and thousands
    return float(value)

data['notional'] = data['Outst'].map(parser)
```